# Magento How to make form fields validation work only when form loses focus

Tags: onepage-checkout, customer-address

When I'm creating new shipping address in Magento after i write one letter in any field all of the fields are being validated. I guess that all the validation is done in my /magento/js/prototype/validation.js file but when I try to comment out onChange event it doesn't take any effect. How can I make validation work only after onblur effect?

Here's my validation.js code for attaching the events:

```
if(this.options.immediate) {
                Form.getElements(this.form).each(function(input) {
                    if (input.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'select') {
                        Event.observe(input, 'blur', this.onChange.bindAsEventListener(this));
                    }
                    if (input.type.toLowerCase() == 'radio' || input.type.toLowerCase() == 'checkbox') {
                        Event.observe(input, 'click', this.onChange.bindAsEventListener(this));
                    } else {
                        Event.observe(input, 'change', this.onChange.bindAsEventListener(this));
                    }
                }, this);
            }
```